# Error syncing pod on starting Beam - Dataflow pipeline from docker

Tags: go, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

We are constantly getting an error while starting our Beam Golang SDK pipeline (driver program) from a docker image which works when started from local / VM instance. We are using Dataflow runner for our pipeline and Kubernetes to deploy.

**LOCAL SETUP**:
We have GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS variable set with service account for our GCP cluster. When running the job from local, job gets submitted to dataflow and completes successfully.

**DOCKER SETUP**:
Build image used is `FROM golang:1.14-alpine`. When we pack the same program with Dockerfile and try to run, it fails with error

```
User program exited: fork/exec /bin/worker: no such file or directory
```

On checking Stackdriver logs for more details, we see this:

```
Error syncing pod 00014c7112b5049966a4242e323b7850 ("dataflow-go-job-1-1611314272307727-
01220317-27at-harness-jv3l_default(00014c7112b5049966a4242e323b7850)"), 
skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "sdk" with CrashLoopBackOff: 
"back-off 2m40s restarting failed container=sdk pod=dataflow-go-job-1-
1611314272307727-01220317-27at-harness-jv3l_default(00014c7112b5049966a4242e323b7850)"
```

Found reference to this error in Dataflow [common errors doc](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/common-errors#error-syncing-pod), but it is too generic to figure out whats failing. After multiple retries, we were able to eliminate any permission / access related issues from pods. Not sure what else could be the problem here.

Comment: Please note that Cloud Dataflow does not officially support Beam Go SDK yet.

Comment: @chamikara Yes we noticed that. It's working for our basic use case as of now. For more advanced pipelines we will probably explore python sdk when required. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After multiple attempts, we decided to start the job manually from a new Debian 10 based VM instance and it worked. This brought to our notice that we are using `alpine` based golang image in Docker which may not have all the required dependencies installed to start the job.

On [golang docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/golang), we found a `golang:1.14-buster` where buster is codename for Debian 10. Using that for docker build helped us solve the issue. Self answering here to help anyone else facing the same issues.